# How to use just first 5 users from CSV fle containing 20 users in JMeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter

I've got a CSV file with login identifiers (there are 20 logins at all). I'd like to use just 5 of them while testing, but with repeating equals 10. So every of those 5 users will be log in to the system 10 times. **How to do this?**

I've done such configuration:
**Thread Group**:
[image]
**CSV Data Set Config**:
[image]

The CSV file is like that:

```
login1
login2
login3
login4
...
login20
```

But while testing I see that not just first 5 users logs in to the system, but also login5, login6, etc.
Why JMeter uses more than 5 users (thread)?
Any ideas for fixing/improving my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter users 5 users however you have 10 iterations therefore there are 50 hits in total.

The only way of implementing your scenario is switching to [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), the relevant code would be something like:

```
${__groovy(new File(vars.get('logins')).readLines().get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0\, 5)),)}
```

[image]

If you don't want the values to be random - consider using [Counter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) test element instead of [RandomUtils.nextInt()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html#nextInt-int-int-) function call